# WKhtmltoimage --scale-w not working

Tags: image, url, webkit, thumbnails, scale

I'm trying to create thumbnail from url with [WKhtmltoImage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) by executing this command :

```
wkhtmltoimage --scale 200 http://google.com google.jpg
```

but return this error :

`Unknown long argument --scale-w`

the version of my wkhtmltoimage is :

`wkhtmltoimage 0.11.0 rc2`

any suggestion please.

Comment: :-? i know there is an option named --zoom but i ca'nt find any manual for it ! :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the zoom option. The following example is running under 0.11.0 rc2:

```
wkhtmltoimage --zoom 0.2 http://abt.net abt.png
```

Comment: This still outputs the file of the image with a bigger resolution and only the actual page has been scaled with a grey background. Is there any way we could get rid of the grey background?

Comment: Probably a way to create a thumbnail version of the main image?

Answer (score 4):

To generate thumbnails, we can use --height and --width option combined with --zoom option.

This works to generate a thumbnail say for example a image size of 300x300:

```
wkhtmltoimage --zoom 0.2 --height 300 --width 300 http://www.bbc.com bbc.jpg
```

wkhtmltoimage version 0.12.2.2

Answer (score 2):

This generate a gray background and doesn't reduce the actual size of the file:

```
wkhtmltoimage --zoom 0.2 http://abt.net abt.png
```